# SQLite: Batch aggregation with insert

Tags: python, select, sqlite, insert, aggregate

I would like to do the following:

```
cur.execute("SELECT key, SUM(val) FROM table GROUP BY key")

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO table_sums VALUES(?,?)",(row for row in cur))
```

in a single SQLite statement with batch processing if possible, that is it does the sum only for a number of keys, inserts, continues till all are processed.

Apparently I am using Python right now but as I am asking for a single statement (if exists), I don't think this should matter. If it doesn't exist, perhaps there is an efficient(!) work-around in Python?

**EDIT:** To avoid a `SELECT WHERE` query, it would actually be desirable not to produce complete sums for a subset of keys, but to just sum over the first `n` rows and store the resulting sums so far, then continue with the next `n`...

Answer (score 2):

The two SQLs could be combined into one using a [temporary view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

```
WITH tempsums as 
(SELECT key,sum(value) from table 
GROUP by key
where key in :batch)
INSERT INTO total_sums SELECT * from tempsums)
```

Comment: So basically, `WITH tmp_sums AS 
(SELECT key, SUM(value) FROM table 
GROUP BY key)
INSERT INTO table_sums SELECT * FROM tmp_sums);`? Because the `WHERE key IN` part would be too expensive. Is there any way to do without a `WHERE`?

Comment: The example WHERE is a proxy for "batch processing". You can do it without the WHERE, it'll insert all of them. It's not clear to me  what the obstacle you are trying to overcome.

Comment: I guess sorting the keys and then going through the first `m` distinct keys and inserting (not updating) is what would be the fastest.